# Non Static Webdriver driver and screenshot listener in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

I having a problem running testing in parallel while capturing screenshots using TestNG listeners.

If I run a **STATIC** webdriver, my tests seems to send the wrong data to each other, but the listener seems to be working....

When I run a **NON STATIC** webdriver, the thread all run correctly in parallel, but I receive a NullPointException on the listener file.

Is there a way around this?? I've looked at running the thread as a threadsafe or threadlocal, but not sure I'm implementing it correctly

Here is my code for my Base class

**BASEREMOTEPARALLEL2.java**

```
package resources;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler;

public class baseRemoteParallel2 {

    public WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver initialiseDriver(String browser) throws IOException {

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Webdriver_Plugins\\chromedriver.exe");

            driver = new ChromeDriver();

        } else if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                    "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Webdriver_Plugins\\geckodriver.exe");

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        } else if (browser.equals("ie")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                    "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Webdriver_Plugins\\IEDriverServer.exe");

            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }

        // Set GLOBAL timeout to 5 seconds
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return driver;
    }

    public void getScreenshotPassed(String result) throws IOException {

        File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        FileHandler.copy(src,
                new File("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Automated_screenshots\\PASSED\\Testname - " + result + ".png"));
    }

    public void getScreenshotFailed(String result) throws IOException {

        File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        FileHandler.copy(src,
                new File("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Automated_screenshots\\FAILED\\Testname - " + result + ".png"));

    }
}
```

This is the code in my Listener.java

```
package resources;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class listeners implements ITestListener {

    baseRemoteParallel2 b = new baseRemoteParallel2();

    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            b.getScreenshotPassed(result.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            b.getScreenshotFailed(result.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

The Error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at resources.baseRemoteParallel.getScreenshotPassed(baseRemoteParallel.java:101)
    at resources.listeners.onTestSuccess(listeners.java:24)
    at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:70)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1389)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:636)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:40)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:489)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Line 101 on my code is this.**

```
    File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Comment: Well you are using a separate instance of your `baseRemoteParallel2` class in your listener. It only worked with the static field, since static fields are shared with all class instances. With normal fields, each instance has its own driver and you need the actual test instance to get the correct driver.

Comment: how can i do this?? can i just call baseRemoteParallel2 using extends?

Comment: Here's a template that uses Threads, has a non-static driver object and manages to take screenshots.  It should help you out:  https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template

Answer (score 0):

You can work with an interface like this:

```
import java.io.File;

public interface RemoteParallelAccess {

  public baseRemoteParallel2 getRemoteAccess();

}
```

Your test class has to implement that interface:

```
class MyTest implements RemoteParallelAccess {

  baseRemoteParallel2 b = new baseRemoteParallel2();

  @Test
  public void doSomeSeleniumStuff() {

  }

  @Override
  public void baseRemoteParallel2 getRemoteAccess() { 
     return b;
  }
}
```

In your listener class you can use

```
if (result.getInstance() instanceof RemoteParallelAccess) {
  RemoteParallelAccess t = (RemoteParallelAccess) result.getInstance();
  baseRemoteParallel2 b = t.getRemoteAccess();
}
```

The interface is a generic way to access the encapsulated webdriver in each test class. If you are using a static webdriver across multiple test classes, the state of the webdriver may be inconsistent. There may be concurrency issues as well with multiple TestNG threads.

Comment: not sure this solution will work, as im using the listener to quickly collect the screenshots of failed tests, im expecting get over 1000 tests, so this approach wont work for me (hence the listeners is really useful). There a way my existing code could access the non static driver????

The code works perfectly, EXCEPT for when running in Parallel.

Comment: Now you should see how to get access to your non-static driver.